# Visual Studio Sharepoint Workflow Deployment

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

Does anyone know how to get VS to show the stsadm.exe commands VS running behind the scenes when it deploys a workflow to Sharepoint 2010?  I'm using VS2010 if it makes a difference.

I'm trying to duplicate all the steps VS takes, with a custom batch file.

Thanks!
Dave

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the Visual Studio Output screen during deployment to see all the steps Visual Studio takes during Deployment. To see this screen go to "View" menu and click on "Output" or press Ctrl+W+O on your keyboard.

Pete

Comment: already done that. Those are just "helpful" descriptions of what VS is doing. for example "deploying workflow"..."retracting workflow".  It doesn't actually show the commands.  But thanks!